React Native android app crashing on startup
I built apk of an expo prebuild app with eas build with following configs
android.compileSdkVersion=33 android.targetSdkVersion=34 android.buildToolsVersion=33.0.0 expo.jsEngine=hermes
"expo": "^48.0.0", "react": "18.2.0", "react-native": "0.71.14",
the apk file install and runs fine on Android Studio Emulator having Android version 13.0 but it is stuck/crashing before splashscreen on Actual android phone having Android Version 14.0. I checked adb logcat and here are the logs.
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.app.investment, PID: 20192
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.lang.Object java.lang.ClassValue.computeValue(java.lang.Class)"
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassValue.getFromHashMap(ClassValue.java:230)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassValue.getFromBackup(ClassValue.java:212)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassValue.get(ClassValue.java:116)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.d.a(Unknown Source:7)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.c.c(Unknown Source:7)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.k0.b(Unknown Source:0)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at kotlin.jvm.internal.a0.b(Unknown Source:2)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at expo.modules.b$a$a.compare(Unknown Source:8)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1270)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at kotlin.collections.l.n(Unknown Source:14)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at kotlin.collections.y.u0(Unknown Source:36)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at kotlin.collections.o.u0(Unknown Source:0)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at expo.modules.b$a.a(Unknown Source:30)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at expo.modules.b$a.g(Unknown Source:0)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at db.t.getValue(Unknown Source:20)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at expo.modules.b$b.a(Unknown Source:4)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at expo.modules.f.<init>(Unknown Source:17)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at expo.modules.e.<init>(Unknown Source:10)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.app.investment.MainApplication.<init>(Unknown Source:10)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(Unknown Source:0)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1353)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1467)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1399)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7359)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2379)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8592)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
07-21 14:55:13.169 20192 20192 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)

Also app is working fine on iOS so it is Android only problem.
